# Action overflow like button at the bottom in Nexus 4

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

[image]

I have designed this simple login screen.
In the LoginActivity, I have not declared **onCreateOptionsMenu** or **onPrepareOptionsMenu**.

But still I am getting **overflow like** button at the screen **bottom right** as shown in the below picture. When I click on it, it does not do anything.

If it were an **Action item** it would be in the **Action Bar** area not along with the device's native soft buttons.

Does anybody know how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set `android:targetSdkVersion="14"` or higher within your `AndroidManifest.xml` to get rid of the "menu button of shame".

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But I don't know what is the reason. (Why it was showing overflow button with absolutely no purpose and no action and setting the targetSDK to 14 it resolved the issue.)

Comment: This is due to changes in the Android platform. The legacy menu button has been disabled for API-Level 14+.